# Resizeimage in matlab

Tags: matlab, conv-neural-network

I have a project in matlab about the detection of traffic signs using deeplearning and I used the cnn algorithm but I can't resize the images, I used the gtsdb database.

```
 folderName = 'Test_rm';
    srcDir = fullfile(folderName);
    srcFiles = dir([srcDir, '*.jpeg']);
    for i = 1:size(srcFiles)
        filename = [srcDir, srcFiles(i).name];
        im = imread(filename);
        k = imresize(im, [240 240]);
        newfilename = [srcDir, srcFiles(i).name];
        imwrite(k, newfilename, 'jpeg');
    end
```

And I keep getting this error: The training images are of size 30×29×3 but the input layer expects images of size 28×28×1.

Thank you for helping me!